# Postgresql function update

Tags: postgresql, function, boolean

I have 2 tables :

1. the first for the calendar with date, and open day (boolean)
2. the second is a table of holidays.

I made a function for change the status of open-day on the calendar :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_hol ()
RETURNS boolean AS
UPDATE calendar SET open_day = 'false'
WHERE day IN (
SELECT jour FROM calendar AS c
INNER JOIN calendar_hol AS h
ON c.day=h.day_hol)
LANGUAGE sql
```

But have always the error message :

> syntax error at or near "UPDATE".

How to correct this, please ? (i tried in a many ways, but with no results...)

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the function body. You can use normal `'` quoting and double all `'`s within the function body, or you can use the PostgreSQL extension `$$` quoting.

Update: Also, as it returns no result, it should be declared `RETURNS void`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_hol ()
RETURNS void AS
$$
UPDATE calendar SET open_day = 'false'
WHERE day IN (
SELECT jour FROM calendar AS c
INNER JOIN calendar_hol AS h
ON c.day=h.day_hol)
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

See the manual for details.

---

Update since you're looking for a trigger procedure but didn't say so.

This doesn't make any sense as a trigger. I think you are *actually* trying to modify a row as it is inserted or updated. To do that, you must set values in the `NEW` variable.

A wild guess, but something like this might be what you are looking for:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_hol ()
RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
  IF tg_op = 'INSERT' OR tg_op = 'UPDATE'
  THEN

    NEW.open_day = NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM calendar_hol AS h
      WHERE h.day_hol = NEW.day
    );

    RETURN NEW;

  END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is a wild guess based on missing information. It might be totally wrong. If you are still stuck after *reading the manual* as linked in the comments, please post a *new question* with a *proper explanation of the problem you are trying to solve*.

Comment: I did it already , but then I get the error : return type mismatch in function declared to return boolean.  If i try RETURNS trigger, have the same problem...

Comment: @Cipango It doesn't return anything, so `RETURNS void`. See the user manual. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html

Comment: yeas, thanks, but then have the error : function add_hol must return type "trigger"...

Comment: @Cipango  Well, if you're trying to create a trigger function, you should've said so. Trigger functions cannot be `LANGUAGE sql`, they must be written in PL/PgSQL. Go read the manual on triggers: [trigger procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) and [`CREATE TRIGGER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html). You have to use `LANGUAGE plpgsql` and wrap it in a `BEGIN...END`. In future questions you should try to explain what you're doing a bit more and show all relevant error messages, etc, to avoid this kind of waste of time.

Comment: ok, sorry. I m lost with this function. I made with plpgsql too, but always something wrong. Then, I don t understand what kind of problem I have. Sorry for the time you waste, I go to read the triggers procedures again.